# CakePHP - Date::i18nFormat() capitalization

Tags: date, cakephp, internationalization, capitalization

I'm using `Date::i18nFormat` to display dates using the desired locale.

This is an example: `$post->date->i18nFormat("dd 'of' MMMM")`. This Outputs: `19 of june`.

I would like to capitalize the first letter of the month, so it would output instead:  `19 of June`.

is it possible?

Thank you

Comment: MMMM should already be giving you June instead of june. Is there some other processing that's happening to lower-case this elsewhere? A further conversion in your code, or a lower-case in your CSS?

Comment: Note that the formatting also depends on the configured locale and the installed ICU library.

Comment: @GregSchmidt I thought MMMM would give me "June" too. But not happening =/. There is no css for conversion to lower case.

Comment: @ndm maybe thats it. This ICU Library is installed in the Linux or is a PHP library?

Comment: ICU is an independent library, the relevant PHP extension that makes use of it is INTL. However IIRC the INTL extension needs to be recompiled against the new ICU version if you wanted to upgrade to a newer ICU version manually. Upgrading PHP, respectively the INTL extension, is what most people usually do. That being said, I'd first make sure that the problem isn't somewhere else.